# create submenu creating all LI with JS, and remove it, using mouseover and mouseleave

Tags: javascript, dom, drop-down-menu

everybody.
I'm studying JS alone, and my exercise this time consists in create sub menus using code, by eventListener 'onmouseover' and 'onmouseleave' properties. I've already done it using pure CSS, but I want to go deeper in DOM manipulation.
Anyway, the code works correctly except for an error when I switch from the main LI without going through the submenu. To expain better,  first I show the details:
Here the HTML part:

```
<div class="nav cn">
  <ul>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#">Dato selezionato</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#">Dato 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS part (only specific) id simple, I report only the sub menu formatting:

```
.sub {
  position: absolute;
  top:105%;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.sub > li {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  color: black;
  top: 85px;
  z-index: 1
}
.sub > li:hover {
  background-color: #e4e773;
}
```

And here is the JS code.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
var subElements = document.getElementsByClassName("sub");
var arrLi1 = ['Dato 1 sub 1', 'Dato 2 sub 1', 'dato 3 sub 1'];
var arrLi2 = ['Dato 1 sub 2', 'Dato 2 sub 2', 'dato 3 sub 2', 'dato 4 sub 2'];

let creaLi = function(itemClass, arr){
  let newUL =document.createElement('UL');
  newUL.className = 'sub';
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    let newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = arr[i];
    newUL.appendChild(newLi);
    itemClass.appendChild(newUL);
  };
  itemClass.getElementsByClassName("sub")[0].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event){
    //-- soluzione 1 (senza il parametro 'event' nella function)
    // console.log(elements[index].getElementsByClassName("sub").length);
    // elements[index].getElementsByClassName("sub")[0].remove();
    // -- soluzione 2, più efficace
    event.target.remove();
  });
};

let creaSub = function(index) {
  elements[index].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
     // alert("Clicked index: " + index);
  if (!this.getElementsByClassName("sub").length > 0) {
      toglisub('sub');
      switch(index){
        case 0: //link a Home
          break;
        case 1:
          creaLi(this, arrLi1);
          break;
        case 2:
          creaLi(this, arrLi2);
          break;
        default:
        }
      };
    });
  };

for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  creaSub(i);
};

let toglisub = function removeElementsByClass(Cls){
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(Cls);
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    };
}
```

Everything works fine except when I move from a item upwards. In that case, it doesn't fire the mouse over, so the submenus is not removed.
I don't understand why. Has someone an explanation for me?

Comment: Could you create a https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Well, many other solutions like that, I suppose, but as I wrote is an exercise, so to learn more I need to understand where is the problem in my code.